# How to check if a string is a number in flink sql

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

In flink sql, how to check whether a string is a number, as

```
select * from input where str like '\\d+'
```

the regular expression seems not useful, and the 'similar to' operator can't work either. Is there some idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try defining a scalar function, here,

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/table/udfs.html#scalar-functions